# ASP.NET - Export formatted data in excel file

Tags: asp.net, formatted

I want to export a datable to excel file. The data should be formatted and in readable format.

Can anyone suggest me ways to do this ?
Also please suggest ready made free library which we can use in ASP.NET for formatted exporting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try http://epplus.codeplex.com/ 
Nowadays I work on exporting excel and this is the best I tried so far.
Easy to use.

Comment: amazing library.. Thank you very much for sharing the link.